# Subquery to Join to understand why subquery is returning more than a single value

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, subquery

I've this query. It functions well when the output of the subquery is a single value; otherwise, it apparently throws an error as it can't be equated with @n. The error is not consistent from database to database. (The error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

)

The easiest work around to solve this is to take the TOP 1 from the subquery. However, before deciding to apply that, I wanted to understand the data and what is causing the subquery output a single value in some databases, but it is multiple making it fail in other databases. In doing so, I was trying to convert the subquery to a join to understand and even to see if there is a better way of solving it. Can anyone help me with converting this to a join? And/or suggest a solution to the error? Thanks.

```
SELECT a.clientid
FROM Clients a
JOIN Ordert b ON a.orderid = b.orderid
WHERE b.deleted=0
    AND b.notifyend=1
    AND (SELECT 
           DATEDIFF(d, CONVERT(Date, GetDate()), CONVERT(Date, c.shipped_on)) 
         FROM shipping c 
         WHERE c.shipping_id = b.shipping_id 
          AND  DATEDIFF(minute,0, c.shipped_on)= 
              (SELECT max(DATEDIFF(minute,0, d.shipped_on)) 
               FROM shipping d 
               WHERE  d.shipping_id = b.shipping_id)) =  @n
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: To Gordon's point, if you try to answer this question, [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), odds are good that you'll also answer your own question. At the very least, though, you'll come up with some sample data we can use to reproduce your issue.

Comment: The first subquery (`SELECT DATEDIFF(d,...`) is returning more than one row and then you want to use the equality comparator (`= @n`). Something smells bad here. That doesn't really work, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored it below to use joins, but it seems like what you want is all rows with max value for your date diff expression datadiff which should be the same as OLDEST-- if that is the case there is a better way using ROW_NUMBER()

```
WITH maxByID AS
(
  select  shipping_id,  max(DATEDIFF(minute,0, shipped_on) as mmax
  FROM shipping
)
SELECT a.clientid
FROM Clients a
JOIN Ordert b ON a.orderid = b.orderid
JOIN maxByID m ON b.shipping_id = m.shipping_id
JOIN shipping c ON c.shipping_id = b.shipping_id and DATEDIFF(minute,0, c.shipped_on) = m.mmax 
WHERE b.deleted=0  AND b.notifyend=1
```